# How to prevent project maintainer add new members in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, addition, member

I want to disallow project maintainer to add new member only, and keep all other maintainer roles. How do I config this rule?

I have local Gitlab 11.9.x version.
I am Owner who create a private project and add new members to team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. As the project maintainer, a user can always add new members. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html for a detailed list of permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Are there any ways to hook/modify gitlab source to apply this modification?

Comment: @GiangNguyen Although not recommended, you can always edit GitLab's code to customise it. Keep in mind this will give you more headaches because of its maintenance and unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Could prevent maintainers from being able to add members to projects in a group
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/access_and_permissions.html#prevent-members-from-being-added-to-projects-in-a-group